# Is there any way to run three python files sequentially as the output of each file depends on the other

Tags: python, csv, file-io, subroutine

I have three python files `file1.py`, `file2.py`, `file3.py`. Each file will generate a `.csv` file and will give it to the other file sequentially. To elaborate `file1.py` will generate `file1.csv` and this `.csv` file will be the input of `file2.py` and so on.

```
 import file1
 import file2
 import file3

 file1
 file2
 file3

 IOError: File file2.csv does not exist
```

The problem is when I import `file2.py`,there is no `file1.csv` as it is yet to be executed. Please let me how to call each one sequentially without even reading the next python file.

Comment: You don't have to import everything at the top. You can import, run, import, run.

Comment: @uʍop ǝpısdn I even tried that but the python will first read all the import files and then it will run the files.

Comment: `but the python will first read all the import files and then it will run the files` <- not always

Comment: It looks like you need some serious refactoring; your scripts shouldn't generally do anything when imported.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am using Canopy as IDE. I am getting errors while import. Will subroutine work? I don't know how to use subroutines.

Comment: I think I have a better idea of what's going on now.... file1.py, etc... should define functions that take a csv file as input and return a csv file as output. Import all the modules at the top and then call the functions one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of your scripts should be set up as a function or class that generates the file. The general structure could be something like this:

```
# file1.py
def generate_csv(filename):
    # put your file generation code here
    # you could easily use Python's csv module, for example
    return csv_filename
```

Then in your main script you can call each of your scripts, like this:

```
# main.py
import file1, file2, file3

def main(filename):
    fname_one = file1.generate_csv(filename)
    fname_two = file2.generate_csv(fname_one)
    fname_three = file3_generate_csv(fname_two)
```

This keeps your original scripts from being run when imported. Your main script controls the order of execution and can do whatever needs to be done to the 3rd file name that is returned.

Comment: I am getting the following error                                         ValueError: No columns to parse from file

Comment: You should be able to use whatever code you already have and just indent it inside of the function. And then return the path of the file it created.

Answer (score 2):

You can pipeline from the command line

```
python file1.py|python file2.py|python file3.py
```

The files would use sys.stdin / sys.stdout as their csv readers / writers.

**EDIT**

You can write a controller script that fires them all off. sys.executable is just the python used to start the script... I'm using it so that the same python is used for all of them.

```
import sys
import subprocess as subp

file1 = subp.Popen([sys.executable, 'file1.py'], stdout=subp.PIPE)
file2 = subp.Popen([sys.executable, 'file2.py'], stdin=file1.stdout, stdout=subp.PIPE)
file3 = subp.Popen([sys.executable, 'file3.py'], stdin=file2.stdout)

# close parent version of pipes
file1.stdout.close()
file2.stdout.close()

# wait for programs to complete
file1.wait()
file2.wait()
file3.wait()
```

Comment: I am using canopy as the IDE. Also i need to run all the files from   one file sequentially.

Comment: @ tdelaney  I am getting AttributeError: type object 'file' has no attribute 'stdout'

Answer (score 0):

If you expect to read from `sys.argv` and output to `stdout` in such a setup *should* work:

```
$ python file3.py $(python file2.py $(python file1.py))
```

*Note: The leading `$` denotes this is a bash shell command.*

Though BE CAUTIOUS. I typically will `$ echo $(python file1.py)` before passing it to the second script, et cetera.